# how can I make my search bar look for a keyword in my database and display it on my webpage

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, database

I want to make this form to search for a keyword in my database that display and highlight it in my webpage with that specific words that is typed in the search bar. purpose of this code is a FAQ for a web-app I'm developing

```
<form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." style=" flex: 1; padding: 12px 20px;  margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box;  border: 2px solid #ccc;  border-radius: 4px; width: 70%;">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" style=" width: auto;  padding: 10px 18px;  background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; margin: 8px 0; border: none;  border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;">
</form>
```

```
 @foreach($kb_info as $kb_info)
    <div class=" {{$kb_info->kb_category}}">
      <a href="/adminkbView/{{$kb_info->kb_ID}}" class="card content {{$kb_info->kb_category}}" id="content clickable" style="margin: 1%; cursor: pointer; text-decoration:  none; color: black;">
        <div class="card-header">
          {{$kb_info->kb_title}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>{{$kb_info->kb_content}}</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer">{{$kb_info->kb_resolution}}<cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

attached image is the preview of my web-page

I tried using this script and it does nothing.

```
 const form = document.getElementById('search-form');
  const input = document.getElementById('search-input');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Searching for: ${input.value}`);
    // Add your search functionality here
  });
```

Comment: Where come from `$kb_info`?

Comment: it is a php code that gets the database from php my admin

 public function admin_KB()
    {

        $kb_info = k_b_s::get();

        return view('admin_KB',['kb_info' => $kb_info]);

    }